# Google drive documents shortcuts not working in Opera

Tags: opera

In google drive docs, there is a shortcut, "Command + Shift + V" for "paste without formatting". When I try to run it in Opera, it doesn't respond in any way.
I have gone to the advanced settings in case this script was assigned, but it is not.
How can I make that command to Paste Plain effective in Google Drive docs?
Thanks

Comment: In what app does this work?